# How do you find the detailed app data usage in android7.0

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring

Before I was able to go into data and on the list of apps pick one and get a chart comparing the global use and the apps use:

[image]

Has this detail view disappeared in Android 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can try wiping your cache partition as suggested [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu18V1JnetUdGZ4/?hl=en):

- Turn off your device
- Press a combination of <kbd>Vol +</kbd>  + <kbd>Vol -</kbd> +  <kbd>Power key</kbd> buttons and hold them down.
- Release only the <kbd>Power</kbd> button when the device vibrates
- Release the other buttons when the **Recovery Menu** screen appears
- Using the <kbd>Vol +</kbd>/<kbd>Vol -</kbd> buttons to navigate, select **Wipe cache partition**
- Press the <kbd>Power key</kbd> , which will act the enter key on your keyboard.
- Wait for the process to finish.
- You can then reboot the device and see if your problems are fixed